# urlib2 HTTP 404: Not found error with Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http, urllib2

I am creating an app on App Engine which needs me to retrieve the entire html of a site. I started trying the urlfetch API, but that only allows you to read the information under the body header, so I tried urllib2.
The application runs fine locally, however when I run it on appspot, I get the HTTP 404 Error.
The relevant code in the program is here:

```
temp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
raw = temp.read()
logging.debug(raw)
self.response.out.write(raw)
```

The url variable has already been defined.
If urllib2 doesn't work on App Engine, then is there a way to get the urlfetch API to do what I want?

Comment: The call you are making to urllib2 is supported https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview so you need to catch the URLError exception and log its contents so you can see what is going wrong. Without that information no one can answer this question.

Comment: The urlfetch api does support reading contents before the body, such as the headers, status_code, final_url. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/responseobjects for details.